# Django JSONField not receiving cleaned data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, django-jsonfield

I have a very simple model which contains a `JSONField`:

```python
class Thing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    text = JSONField(default=dict)
```

I've created a custom widget that allows for the input of key-value pairs:

```py
class JsonWidget(forms.widgets.Widget):
    template_name = 'json_widget.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        data = json.loads(value)
        if not data:
            data = JSON_DEFAULT
        context['data'] = data.items()
        return context

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        keys = data.getlist('json-key')
        values = data.getlist('json-value')
        json_data = {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, values)}
        return json_data
```

I coerce the `dict` returned by the widget into a string in the field's `clean` function on the form:

```python
class ThingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Thing
        fields = ['title', 'text']
        widgets = {
            'text': JsonWidget(),
        }

    def clean_text(self):
        text = self.cleaned_data.get('text')
        return json.dumps(text)
```

I've inspected the output of `JsonWidget.value_from_datadict` (`dict`) and `ThingForm.clean_text` (`str`) are the expected types. But when the object goes to save it throws an exception:

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'
```

This is my first time building a custom widget for Django 1.11, is there something obvious I've missed here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was a tricky one but I eventually traced the problem back to [Instance construction fails on form data check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661557/instance-construction-fails-on-form-data-check)

While the `JSONField` is called `text` on the model, there's no matching field on the `ModelForm`. Instead, the key/value pairs are compiled & turned into a `dict` by the widget's `value_from_datadict`. However, the `cleaned_data` values are saved back to the instance *only* if the field name exists in the form's POST data. This caused the widget to throw an error because `text` could not be blank, and the `TypeError` exception was raised during the form re-render.

The workaround was to add a hidden input called `text` to the field and *only* use it to bypass the field name check during instantion.